# how do i make this code continuously execute even after releasing the "x" key?

Tags: python, pygame

I want the if statement to continuously execute the code beneath it, however I am unsure of what I should do. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

p.s sorry if my terminology is wrong as I am new to programming

```
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if key [pygame.K_x]:
    screen.blit (bg, (0, 0))
    player.update()
    kivotos.draw()
    obusutakuru.update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a variable remember if the x-key has been pressed

```py
# outside the game loop
xKeyPressed = False

.....

# inside the game loop
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if key[pygame.K_x]:
    xKeyPressed = True

if xKeyPressed:
    screen.blit (bg, (0, 0))
    player.update()
    kivotos.draw()
    obusutakuru.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to be drawn permanently, you need to draw it in the application loop but not only when a key is hold down.
Also [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) is not the right choice, because it returns a sequence with the current state of each key. For example, use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement.
You have to use the key board events. The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. `KEYUP` occurs once every time a key is released. Use the keyboard events for a single action:

```py
run = True
while run:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                xKeyPressed = True 
    
    if xKeyPressed:
        screen.blit (bg, (0, 0))
        player.update()
        kivotos.draw()
        obusutakuru.update()
```